# Im getting name error when running this code

Tags: python-3.x, request

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

session = request.session()

def get_sizes_in_stock():
    global session
    endpoint = "https://www.off---white.com/en/SE/men/products/omia065r208000010100#"
    response = session.get(endpoint)

    soup = bs(response.text,"html.parser")

    ul = soup.find("ul",{"class":"styled-radio"})
    all_sizes = ul.find_all("li")

    sizes_in_stock = []
    for size in all_sizes:
        if "availability not_on_sale" not in size["class"]:
            size_id = size["id"]
            sizes_in_stock.append(size_id.split("_")[1])

    return sizes_in_stock

print(get_sizes_in_stock())
```

The error received is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\arvid\Desktop\python tings\owbot.py", line 4, in <module>
    session = request.session()
NameError: name 'request' is not defined
>>>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please accept answers when they solve your problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for the FAQ

Answer (score 0):

You are mis-spelling `requests` in `session = request.session()`.

The library is `requests` (plural)